# Clearing Cells automatically

Tags: google-sheets

When editing in google sheets, the selected cell will clear the current data after 30-40 seconds.  What steps can we take to stop this action to automatically clear?

Comment: interesting... sounds like browser, keyboard or extension issue

Answer (score 0):

To stop clearing cells, you need to double click on any cell, and then press the insert button, the overwrite will toggle off for not only that cell but also for the entire application.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I followed these steps but it still didn't make a difference in the outcome.  After 30-40 seconds, the cell automatically clears.  Is there some other steps to take to get this to stop?????